# How does CanBuildFrom know whether a type can build from another?

Tags: scala

I read the [official doc](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/architecture-of-scala-collections.html) but I can't still understand how it works. For example:

```
class A {
  type Self
}
def seqToSet[T <: A](seq: Seq[T])
                    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[T], T#Self, Set[T]]) {}
```

The above code can be compiled... but how? How does Scala know a `Set` can be built from a `Seq`? And how could it ensure a `T#Self`(literally any type) can be put into `Set[T]`?

Comment: This may be helpful to you: http://blog.bruchez.name/2012/08/getting-to-know-canbuildfrom-without-phd.html

Answer (score 3):

It don't know it in general. You should provide such `CanBuildFrom`.

For simple cases like this you could use `breakOut`:

```
class A1 extends A { type Self = A1 }
seqToSet(new A1 :: Nil)(collection.breakOut)
// compiles fine
```

For more complicated case:

```
case class A2(val i: Int) extends A {
  type Self = Int
}

implicit val A2cbf = new CanBuildFrom[Seq[A2],A2#Self,Set[A2]] {
  import scala.collection.mutable.Builder
  class A2Builder extends Builder[A2#Self,Set[A2]] {
    var es = List[A2]()
    def +=(elem: A2#Self): this.type = { es ::= A2(elem); this }
    def clear(): Unit = es = Nil
    def result(): Set[A2] = es.toSet
  }
  def apply() = new A2Builder
  def apply(from: Seq[A2]) = apply()
}

seqToSet(new A2 :: Nil)(collection.breakOut)
// compiles fine
```

You should provide `Builder` (using `CanBuildFrom`) such that it accepts `A2#Self` in method `+=` and returns `Set[A2]` as result. In code sample it creates new `A2` using `elem`: `A2(elem)`.

Let's create more useful method with almost the same parameters:

```
def seqToSet[T <: A](seq: Seq[T])(f: T => T#Self)
                    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[T], T#Self, Set[T]]) = {
  seq.map{f}: Set[T]
}

seqToSet(A2(1) :: A2(2) :: Nil){ a2 => a2.i + 1 }
// Set[A2] = Set(A2(3), A2(2))
```

This method provides some strange transformation of `A` with transformation of collection type.

Answer (score 2):

`CanBuildFrom[A,B,C]` is an implicit and it follows implicit resolution rules determined by the language specification. You can actually look directly here [Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits) to find all the details.

So the answer is:

```
def seqToSet[T <: A](seq: Seq[T])
                    (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Seq[T], T#Self, Set[T]]) {}
```

will compile if there is a `CanBuildFrom[Seq[T],T#Self, Set[T]]` in scope, and will fail to compile if there is not. If there is, someone has provided an implementation for it, which means the operation is possible (`CanBuildFrom` is a trait, so an instance is a concrete implementation of it)

With collections, the approached that the library designer decided to follow is to place the implicits in the companion objects : above you see Seq.scala from 2.10.3

```
trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int, A]
                      with Iterable[A]
                      with GenSeq[A]
                      with GenericTraversableTemplate[A, Seq]
                      with SeqLike[A, Seq[A]] {
  override def companion: GenericCompanion[Seq] = Seq

  override def seq: Seq[A] = this
}

/** $factoryInfo
 *  The current default implementation of a $Coll is a `List`.
 *  @define coll sequence
 *  @define Coll `Seq`
 */
object Seq extends SeqFactory[Seq] {
  /** $genericCanBuildFromInfo */
  implicit def canBuildFrom[A]: CanBuildFrom[Coll, A, Seq[A]] = ReusableCBF.asInstanceOf[GenericCanBuildFrom[A]]

  def newBuilder[A]: Builder[A, Seq[A]] = immutable.Seq.newBuilder[A]
}
```