# Correct way to develop generic modifiers in Java

Tags: java, oop, generics, collections

In Java, we have functions of the sort:

```
public Collection<String> removeNulls(Collection<String> input) {
    List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
    return output;
}
```

Do note that I am not modifying the input in any way because a lot of time we happen to use `ImmutableList` for the List. More commonly, we try to ensure immutability in functions to whatever degree possible. However, a pitfall I see here is that, all my methods very often use their own implementation of `Collection`. If somebody using my library was using `LinkedList` or a `Set` or a `SortedSet`, an assumption like "lookups are `O(1)`" or "the list is always sorted" breaks whenever my function is called on their list:

```
Set<String> mySet = new SortedSet<>();
mySet.add(10);
mySet.add(9); // I know that my collection is now sorted
Collection<String> myFilteredSet = removeNulls(mySet); // It is no longer sorted
Set<String> mySet = Sets.newSortedSet(myFilteredSet); // Have to sort it again
```

In case of a `LinkedList`, this becomes even more subtle, if my function were to return a `List`, then I would continue to use the list. It won't have any compile-time errors, nor would the problem we visible to me. In the previous case the problem was atleast visible because I still had to convert the returned Collection (or List) to a Set and I knew what was up. The problem would only arise later on, if there was some heavy processing going on which depended on a `LinkedList` being used. An ideal way (that does not mean "recommended" though) would be:

```
public List<String> removeNulls(List<String> input) {
    List<String> output = (List<String>)input.getClass().newInstance();
    // ...
    return output;
}
```

This way, I am ensuring that atleast the same implementation of a type is being used. What, in your opinion, the solution to this problem?

**EDIT**

Just to clarify a bit, I do not actually have a removeNulls method and that is not what I am looking for. This question does not pertain to a real-life problem, but is more of a "something to think about". In other words, my question would be, given that you give me a collection, I have to return another collection that is somehow derived from it and does not modify the input, how do I ensure that my output collection adheres to the contracts (or specifically, the implementation) of the input collection?

Comment: If you can't develop a more unified API, it might be a good idea to put critical assumptions (especially those you can't enforce programmatically) as a precondition of sorts in your documentation, so programmers that break that precondition have no one to blame but themselves when they use your library function improperly. It does seem to me like there are some API design issues going on...

Comment: I think the point is that the input/original collection may not be changed and the caller gets a new list, so he ends up with tow list the original and the new one without nulls, probably the original list may be needed as is somewhere else.

Comment: You can ensure that the result collection is of the same type as the input collection syntactically by changing the signature to `<E, C extends Collection<E>> C removeNulls(C input)`, but you still have to instantiate the result collection via reflection. Anyway, the real problem is that you do not know how to process the elements correctly. Even in this simple example, image a collection which stores `null`s in a separate collection internally. Then, `removeNulls` would be implemented differently. The collection implementations should decide how to do it. A generic solution wont help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, what you want is to amend the Collection interface with the operation `withoutNulls`, and implement it accordingly, but since you cannot 'add' a new method to the existing collection classes, you are out of luck. But, since you often use your own collection implementations, maybe you can extend *your* interfaces and provide some methods to convert regular collection classes to your own.

Something like this:

```
public interface BetterCollection<E> extends Collection<E> {
    BetterCollection<E> withoutNulls();
}

public class BetterLinkedList<E> extends LinkedList<E> implements BetterCollection<E> {
    public BetterLinkedList() {}

    public BetterLinkedList(LinkedList<E> input) {
        super(input);
    }

    @Override
    public BetterCollection<E> withoutNulls() {
        BetterCollection<E> result = new BetterLinkedList<E>();
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

I think in C# it is possible to use extension methods, however you are somewhat limited in the implementation (for example you cannot access private fields and I am not sure whether they can be virtual).

Another solution in Java would be to overload the methods and make them accept different collection types, like `removeNulls(LinkedList<String>)` or `removeNulls(SortedSet<String>)`, but it obviously has its drawbacks too.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that your approach needs to change.

There is little purpose in creating immutable collections if you need to adjust them later. Collections should be made immutable just prior to being exposed to the outside world (if necessary). Therefore, you should operate solely on modifiable collections and allow your method to adjust the argument.

If you receive an immutable collection from elsewhere, convert that into a modifiable collection and then follow the approach above.

Answer (score 2):

The `removeNulls` method is a very "simple" example, and it's hard to imagine what further kinds of "modifiers" you may be working with.

From your description, it sounds that your actual intention might nicely be supported by the new [Streams API in Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/). For example, removing the `null` elements from a `Stream` could easily be accomplished with

```
// Filter out all null elements
collection.stream().filter((e) -> e != null).... // Further operations
```

The nice thing here is that your *actual* problem is handled internally: The [characteristics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html#characteristics--) of the stream are (as far as possible) preserved during the operations. For example, a stream that was sorted before will remain sorted.

---

An alternative way of handling such a situation for pre-Java-8 versions is to specify the output collection (or at least, give the option to do so). For the example: You could write the method as

```
public <T> Collection<T> removeNulls(Collection<? extends T> input, Collection<T> output)
{
    if (output == null) 
    {
        // Create some default collection or
        // report an error...
    }
    for (T t : input)
    {
        if (t != null)
        {
            output.add(t);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

// Convenience method
public <T> Collection<T> removeNulls(Collection<? extends T> input)
{
    return removeNulls(input, new ArrayList<T>());
}
```

To be called as

```
Set<String> mySet = new SortedSet<>();
mySet.add(10);
mySet.add(9); // I know that my collection is now sorted
Collection<String> myFilteredSet = removeNulls(mySet, new SortedSet<>());
```

(Note: One could even further exploit the power of type inference and generics here - this ist just to show the basic idea)

---

In any case, I consider it as **very** important to clearly **specify** any assumptions as pre- and postconditions in the *JavaDoc*, e.g.

```
/** 
 * Creates a new collection with the same contents as the given collection,
 * but without any <code>null</code> entries
 *
 * The order of output elements will be the same as the input elements
 * or alternatively:
 * No assumptions may be made about the order of the output collection
 *
 * @return The filtered collection
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

As for the property "sorted", filters according to

```
public Collection<String> someFilter(Collection<String> input)
```

might be written in a way that permits you to guarantee that the property "sorted" is not violated, i.e., the filter is "stable".

For instance, iterating the input collection and storing whatever passes the filter in an ArrayList and returning that will be "stable".

(Of course, there may be transformation where you cannot guarantee that.)

Another property would be the preservation of "object identity" as opposed to copying, but this is a little more esoteric ;-)

Comment: While this preserves the sorted property it violates the expectation that you want to get a Set out, when you put a set in.

Comment: Why should I expect that? And, more importantly, who'd make the *extreme* effort to comply with this? If "Set-preserving" or "List-preseving" are interesting properties - great, and show it in the types. But a general "Collection-type preserving" - I don't know...

Comment: "Why should I expect that?" For the same reason one might expect Sort preservation. "Who'd make the extreme effort[..]?" The Scala guys did.

Comment: I'm not saying your solution is wrong or something. Just pointing out the limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer use Scala.

More serious answer: Have a look at the Scala collection library especially the [BuildFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762449/how-does-canbuildfrom-know-whether-a-type-can-build-from-another).

The basic idea is that you provide a factory that is able to create the proper return collection if possible. Your idea of creating the collection based on the class of the input parameter is a good step in the right direction.

The complete Scala version would be rather complicated, because the user would have to provide the correct BuildFrom on her own, and can't rely on Scalas implicit magic to provide the right one in 98% of the cases. But studying it will give you lot's of ideas, what you might worry about and how possibly to solve it. If you really want to do it in the end is then up to you.