# Scala compiler doesn't behave as expected with use of an implicit val set to null

Tags: scala

I encountered this very peculiar behaviour that had me stumped for quite awhile. I've re-created it in a simple snippet below, code is lifted from Scala wrapper.

```
scala> def a = {
 | implicit val u = null
 | val x: Int = List(1,2,3).map(_.toString)
 | }
a: Unit
```

In the code above, there is no error thrown even though I know the type of val x to be List[String]. I can change the type of x to Int, Long, etc. and it will continue to compile fine.

However when I add explicitly state a type for the implicit val u, like in the example below, the compiler behaves as expected and throws an error.

```
scala> def a = {
 | implicit val u: Any = null
 | val x: Int = List(1,2,3).map(_.toString)
 | }
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[String]
 required: Int
```

Has anyone else experienced this or has any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: A good reason not to use `null` and implicits without explicit types.

Comment: `implicit val u = null` says "I want to put an implicit value in scope for any type whatsoever and I want everything to blow up at runtime whenever that value is used".

Comment: @TravisBrown it's also a handy home remedy for those pesky `import language._` thingies. Might as well put those unused nulls to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Due to how collections are designed in scala, `null` gets picked up as the implicit parameter of `map`, which has the following extended signature:

```
def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

In this specific example, the implicit parameter must be a `CanBuildFrom[List[Int], String, Int]`, and unfortunately `null` is a bottom type so it satisfies such requirement.

Check this QA for more details: [How does CanBuildFrom know whether a type can build from another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762449/how-does-canbuildfrom-know-whether-a-type-can-build-from-another)

You can reproduce it without the implicit like this:

```
@ def a = {
    val x: Int = List(1,2,3).map(_.toString)(null)
  }
defined function a
```

Then, when you actually run the function, it tries to apply the builder but it's null, so... BOOM!

```
@ a
java.lang.NullPointerException
        scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.builder$1(TraversableLike.scala:240)
        scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        cmd3$.a(Main.scala:52)
        cmd4$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Main.scala:52)
        cmd4$.<init>(Main.scala:53)
        cmd4$.<clinit>(Main.scala:-1)
```

you can see in the stacktrace that everything breaks as soon as the implementation of map on `TraversableLike` tries to access `builder`, which happens to be `null`.

Answer (score 4):

When you look at the signature of `map` you see that there is an implicit argument:

```
 def map[B, That](f: A => B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[List[A], B, That]): That
```

When the compiler sees the implicit value inside the scope of call to `map` it seems to assume that it is supposed to be a `CanBuildFrom[List[Int], String, Int]`. So it expands to:

```
def a = {
  implicit val u: CanBuildFrom[List[Int], String, Int] = null
  val x: Int = List(1, 2, 3).map(_.toString)(u)
}
```

When you try to use it though, you can expect a `NullPointerException`.

Now, when you give `u` an explicit type the compiler can no longer find or infer a `CanBuildFrom` that would give the result type `Int`.